# OSX Calendar zoom in on specific date

Tags: calendar

In OSX Calendar (El Capitan) I am on the "Month" view. I browse around and then I see a date that interests me and want to see a full day-view for that date.

My instinct is to double-click on the date, but it creates a new event.

How do I zoom into a specific date?

Comment: Click on it on month view and then press `⌘ CMD`+`1` to switch to day view.

Answer (score 1):

Just double click exactly on the number of the day, instead of double-clicking in the "body" of the day.

[image]

For example, if you want to have a day view for July 1st, double-click on the "1 Jul".

Comment: aha. Yes, I tried that as well but my calendar has 2 numbers (using the alternate calendar feature). And I guess I was clicking on the wrong one. Thanks